# Mongo error - Can't canonicalize query: BadValue Unsupported projection option

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to MongoDB and trying to execute a query. I have a company collection and company IDs array. I would like to get the results where `attributes.0.ccode` exist and `attributes.0.ccode` is not empty and will be checked within the ids provided in an array( `cdata`)

```
var query = Company.find({ _id: { $in: cdata } },{ "attributes.0.ccode": { $exists: true }, $and: [ { "attributes.0.ccode": { $ne: "" } } ] }).select({"attributes": 1}).sort({});
```

The error I am getting is

```
"$err": "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue Unsupported projection option: attributes.0.ccode: { $exists: true }",
"code": 17287
```

I think it's a bracketing issue but can't figure it out where.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `{ _id: { $in: cdata } }` is interpreted as query, and everything else, starting from `,{ "attributes.0.ccode": { $e..` as a Projection (which field to display). Try to refactor your code so `_id: {$in ...}` and the rest of the query belong to the same higher - level object. Something like this:

```
var query = Company.find({
  _id: {
    $in: cdata
  },
  "attributes.0.ccode": {
    $exists: true
  },
  $and: [
    {
      "attributes.0.ccode": {
        $ne: ""
      }
    }
  ]
}).select({"attributes": 1}).sort({});
```